# AngularJS (CoffeeScript): $interval only runs once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, timeout

I am currently trying to repeat a function on a regular interval using the $interval function that comes with AngularJS. The following is a code snippet:

```
angular.module('tetris-controller', ['tetris-model'])
.controller('tetrisCtrl', [
  '$rootScope', '$scope', '$interval', '$timeout', ...,
  ($rootScope, $scope, $interval, $timeout, ...) ->

    ...

    tick = ->
      console.log("tick")
      $rootScope.count++
      $scope.game.block.down()
      $rootScope.tetris_game = $scope.game.grid.drawText()

    tick()
    $interval tick 500

    ...

])
```

When running this code, only two "tick"s are output to console. I have also tried using $timeout, but the delay does not seem to work properly (i.e. "tick" outputs to console with any delay in between).

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$interval tick 500` will transcompile to: `$interval(tick(500));`

What you need is: `$interval tick, 500`

Which will become: `$interval(tick, 500);`